# Hibernate @Formula for timestamp to date conversion in order by

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I already solved this but I didn't have much success just searching for what was my final solution and well maybe there is more than 1 way to do this but I wanted to share what I came up with and maybe it will be of some use.

My problem was with Hibernate I was performing a query that has paging and the result set needed to be sorted in a particular order. The sort was to use record creation date but that is a time stamp down to the millisecond and we wanted the day month year to be equivalent The timestamps could have been hours apart or a few milliseconds but if they were both on June 5 2000 they should be treated as equal. I found a lot of information on how to extract year month or day from a date but not actually do a conversion. How do I do this then?

Comment: JPA has no such `@Formula`, so suggest that you fix your title

Comment: confused by your comment. Title says 'Hibernate @Formula.... ' .    The import statement is: import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;   You're mentioning JPA.

Comment: You had the title as "JPA @Formula", I asked you to change it. Nothing happened, so I changed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This ends up being a calculated field basically so in comes the @Formula annotation. I had discovered in SQL server the convert function which did what I wanted. Getting it into the Formula there was a bit of a trick. I came up with this:

```
@Formula("convert( \"date\", Date_Time_Created ) ")
```

putting in date by itself ending up date being treated as member variable, just doing single quotes 'date' literally went to SQL as 'date', but adding the double quotes as being escaped resulted in "date" in the sql but that worked.